# Solving a circuit with node voltage method

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, ohms-law, kirchhoffs-laws

I have the following circuit:

[image: Given diagram of the circuit]

Knowns:

Iz = 80 mA

R1 = 100 Ohms
R2 = 150 Ohms
R3 = 220 Ohms
R4 = 330 Ohms
R5 = 100 Ohms

1. As I understand Gi stand for the current source internal conductivity, but provided only the current Iz how can I calculate it? My guess is I need to know the resistance of the whole circuit...
2. How to calculate the resistance of this whole circuit, I tried simplifying but as it seems to me there is nothing to simplify
3. How to solve it using node voltage method, preferably if you can elaborate step by step so I understand it

If anyone helped it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have a delta at the top you can convert into a star. http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/dcp_10.html

Comment: is there any universal method, more like an algorithm?

Comment: Also I don't see how is this a delta, can you please elaborate?

Comment: R1 R2 and R3 is a delta... and yes read that link, the equations are in there. There are probably calculators on line too.

Comment: Thank you for that!
Is there an universal method to solve a circuit like this? More like algorithmic one?

Comment: Only for the parts, you have to work through it logically best you can.

Comment: Alright, and what about number 1 in my question? What is this Gi?

Comment: If Gi is indeed the conductivity of the current source.. and you can calculate the voltage across the latter, and knowing Iz, you ought to be able to figure out the effective resistance/conductance of the source. Odd way to draw it though.

Comment: @slimDeviant The nodal method is algorithmic and can be applied. However, without knowing \$G_i\$ it will not be possible to provide quantities. To see why, just imagine you have converted \$R_1\$ through \$R_5\$ into an equivalent resistor across \$G_i\$, \$R_{eq}\$. You have two knowns, now: \$I_z\$ and \$R_{eq}\$. But two unknowns: \$G_i\$ and the voltage across \$I_z\$ (call it \$V_z\$.) So that's it without added information.